# My first vps! Where to start?

Tags: php, mysql, vps

I just got my first vps which i will use for an online game. However, I have only worked with normal webhost so far (with control panel, mysql, php, phpmyadmin already installed), and I have no idea what to do now. The only thing I have is the ip adress, username and password to the vps.

I would like to have some kind of control panel to login to see some stats, phpmyadmin to control the mysql database, and the ability to upload and store the .php files thats talks with the mysql db. I read a little about LAMP (apache), is that good?
Where do I start?

Many thanks

VPS os is debian 6. 
Im using a mac

Comment: You shouldn't be managing a machine - no matter if dedicated or virtual - that is most likely connected with 100mbps to the public internet without any knowledge on linux administration...

Comment: I'd beg to differ - depending on the *use* of that machine, his VPS project is a good way to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Linode library](http://library.linode.com/lamp-guides/debian-6-squeeze) and [Slicehost articles](http://articles.slicehost.com/debian-lenny) are good places to start.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps check out webmin (http://www.webmin.com/) for a control panel, and howtoforge (http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_debian_lamp_server) - there are tons of tutorials out there to get you started (google is your friend), and no one simple answer.  NARKOZ suggestions are very good too.